# How to handle logic chain of filters of shell commands?

Tags: c, shell, operating-system

I was reading an Operating Systems book and found this example to work. I understood what `ps -elf | less` was doing. The `|` (pipe) works as a bridge between `ps -elf` and `less` command and takes the output of `ps -elf` as input to `less`.

But going in much deeper in the shell commands I'm trying to understand what would

`ps -elf | grep "/usr" | wc –l` do?

In this case, there are two `|` (pipes) and the logic is the same. But I cannot implement it into a working example. If you know how to do it, it would make it very clear for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fds[2];
    char buf[30];
    pid_t pid1, pid2, pid;
    int status, i;

    /* create a pipe */
    if (pipe(fds) == -1) {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
    }

    /* fork first child */
    if ( (pid1 = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
    }

    if ( pid1 == 0 ) {
        close(1);  /* close normal stdout (fd = 1) */
        dup2(fds[1], 1);   /* make stdout same as fds[1] */
        close(fds[0]); /* we don't need the read end -- fds[0] */

        if( execlp("ps", "ps", "-elf", (char *) 0) < 0) {
        perror("Child");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* control never reaches here */
    } 

    /* fork second child */
    if ( (pid2 = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
    }

    if ( pid2 == 0 ) {
        close(0);   /* close normal stdin (fd = 0)*/
        dup2(fds[0],0);   /* make stdin same as fds[0] */
        close(fds[1]); /* we don't need the write end -- fds[1]*/

        if( execlp("less", "less", (char *) 0) < 0) {
        perror("Child");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* control never reaches here */
    }

    /* parent doesn't need fds  - MUST close - WHY? */
    close(fds[0]); 
    close(fds[1]); 

    /* parent waits for children to complete */
    for( i=0; i<2; i++) {
        pid = wait(&status);
        printf("Parent: Child %d completed with status %d\n", pid, status);
    }
}
```

[image: Output for the program]

Answer (score 2):

When creating pipes, you need to start with the **last** command in the pipeline and work backwards from that.  By doing so, each program you start is waiting for output from the prior command in the pipeline.  If you start from the front, the first program can finish before you have a chance to start the second one, resulting in the pipe being closed.

In this case, you run `less` first.  That sits waiting for output which hasn't come yet.  Then you run `ps`, and its output gets fed to `less`.

```
/* fork first child */
if ( (pid1 = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}

if ( pid1 == 0 ) {
    close(0);   /* close normal stdin (fd = 0)*/
    dup2(fds[0],0);   /* make stdin same as fds[0] */
    close(fds[1]); /* we don't need the write end -- fds[1]*/

    if( execlp("less", "less", (char *) 0) < 0) {
        perror("Child");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* control never reaches here */
} 

/* fork second child */
if ( (pid2 = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}

if ( pid2 == 0 ) {
    close(1);  /* close normal stdout (fd = 1) */
    dup2(fds[1], 1);   /* make stdout same as fds[1] */
    close(fds[0]); /* we don't need the read end -- fds[0] */

    if( execlp("ps", "ps", "-elf", (char *) 0) < 0) {
        perror("Child");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* control never reaches here */
}
```

Comment: What does the chronological order of process creation have to do with the topology of the pipe connections?

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you start the pipeline from the front, one application can finish and close the pipe before the next one is started.  Starting from the end prevents these type of timing issues, and I believe it's how most shells do it as well.

Comment: Thanks. It could be useful to include that in the answer. And I would wonder if it matters. If the first process finishes, and then you fork to create the second process, the second process should still inherit your pipe context, so it should still be able to read whatever data is in the pipe buffer and then get the close/EOF indication, shouldn’t it?

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. I was understanding it the wrong way. But the main question was this `ps -elf | grep "/usr" | wc –l`. How does this command work? How do I implement it to get a better idea of how these pipes work.

Comment: @RajatGupta You need to create two pipes in that case.  The first is between `grep` and `wc` and the second between `ps` and `grep`.  Start `wc` reading from the first pipe, then start `grep` writing to the first and reading from the second, then start `ps` writing to the second.